# Update a value in mysql which is referenced from another table without cascade

Tags: mysql

Assume 'id' is PK of table A.
Assume 'a_id' is FK referring to table A in table B

I have not set up cascading on update.

Now how do I update the id of one of the rows in table A? (obviously constraint will fail if simple `update table` command is issued)

Comment: Why would you want to edit the `id` field? After all a primary key is just a unique identifier.

Comment: I started it as 1, 2, 3 and so on - today I want it to start from 2000, 2001 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. drop the FK constraint
2. fix your data
3. recreate the FK constraint

I suspect that "fixing your data" could probably be achieved by *inserting* a new row with an ID of what you were going to update the existing row with, instead of updating a row: You'll still need the old ID if any rows in B point to it.

Comment: Well, I thought you would ask me to add `on update cascade`, update the table and then remove the cascade :)